# Cannot purchase app on SharePoint Marketplace - Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: 2013

When I try to purchase an app from the SharePoint Marketplace I receive the following error message:

> Sorry, something went wrong.
>   Sorry, we couldn’t complete your purchase. Please try again later.

I am able to develop and deploy (SharePoint hosted) apps on my SharePoint 2013 environment.
I am located in the Netherland (don't know if that could be the issue).

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

*

> Ok I figured it out. The machine from which I was visiting the
>   SharePoint Marketplace  was configured with an incorrect date.

*

Regards 
Gijs

Comment: If you want to put that as an answer and mark it correct, you can!

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the tip, I tried to answer my own question and apparently users with no reputation (like me)are not allowed to answer their own questions within eight hours..

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me when I was logged in with the SP_Farm Account. When I logged in with a normal Farm administrator account it worked.